# Model Target guideview not properly working through web API

Tags: c#, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am trying to create a "Standard Model Target" through the web API using c# and I have set up all the authentication and API calls however my guideview is not properly shown ([here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0FnV.jpg)) in the Vuforia Test app.
Here is my JSON request body:

```
string requestBody = @"
{
    ""name"": ""mm_frame"",
    ""targetSdk"": ""10.18"",
    ""models"": [
        {
            ""name"": ""mm_frame"",
            ""cadDataUrl"": ""Link to my 3D model"",
            ""cadDataFormat"": ""OBJ"",

            ""views"": [
                {
                    ""name"": ""GuideView"",
                    ""layout"": ""portrait"",
                    ""guideViewPosition"": {
                        ""translation"": [0, 0, 5],
                        ""rotation"": [0,0,0,1]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    ""uniformScale"": 1
}";
```

And this is the guideview that I am getting which is not properly working

I tried setting the "translation" and the "rotation" values based on what I am seeing in the "Model Target Generator" software but literally no change is being made